# Dificuldade em usar o LAG para pegar o percentual de evolução mensal

Tags: mysql

tenho a seguinte tabela abaixo e gostaria de pegar a evolução (%) mensal do total de transações por mês. Pesquisei sobre a função LAG mas não consegui entender muito bem.

Preciso que o retorno dessa consulta seja assim:

```
MÊS | TOTAL TRANSACOES | % EVOLUCAO
-----------------------------------
09  | 45.561 | 0%

10  | 48.598 | 6.66%
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campanha` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ano_mes` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valor` float(10,2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `transacoes` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Versão MySQL: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f38f/2

Comment: Ninguém para ajudar? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campanha` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ano_mes` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `transacoes` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO campanha (ano_mes, transacoes) VALUES ('2019-09-01', 45561);
INSERT INTO campanha (ano_mes, transacoes) VALUES ('2019-10-01', 48598);

SELECT mes, transacoes, evolucao FROM (
  SELECT 
    mes, 
    transacoes,
    IFNULL(transacoes * 100 / @lastValue - 100, 0) AS evolucao,
    @lastValue := transacoes
  FROM (
    SELECT MONTH (ano_mes) AS mes, SUM(transacoes) AS transacoes FROM campanha,
    (SELECT @lastValue := 0) SQLVars GROUP BY mes) meio
) final;
```

Output:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| mes  | transacoes | evolucao |
+------+------------+----------+
|    9 |      45561 |   0.0000 |
|   10 |      48598 |   6.6658 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: A saída não ficou agrupado pelo "mês". Ficou várias linhas com cada mês

Comment: @gugoan editei a resposta... mas poderá haver maneiras mais simples

Comment: Ah sim, funcionou certinho. Muito bom.